# Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/sites/northwells.co.uk/.../sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 281

Tags: php, string, function, prestashop

I'm using Prestashop 1.5.4.1 and after installing a new template, I get this error:

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/sites/northwells.co.uk/.../sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 281

The code in line 281 says:

```
$_template->properties['unifunc']($_template);
```

What could be wrong? I don't really know much about PHP. Many thanks for your help.

Raf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug that was fixed in Prestashop 1.5.5

http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/205130-blank-page-when-cache-enabled/

Comment: Thanks dprogramz. Much appreciated. It seems to be an issue with cache, when I disable cache completely, store works fine. Should I just keep the cache disabled?

Comment: caches are typically used as a performance enhancement, so I think performance is the only thing you are sacrificing by turning it off. Obviously it would be good to find the root of the problem, but I don't think you will break your project by turning it off :)

Comment: Great, you saved me. Many thanks. I was just setting up a new store and encountered this problem. I spent good few hours searching what the issue could be. Obviously I'm still quite far away from people storming my shop purchasing so I'll keep it OFF for now and probably upgrade the prestashop later. Many thanks again dprogramz.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the best solution but since i can't update the version of prestashop because my theme, in modules\blockcategories\blockcategories.php, i comment lines with:
Tools :: enableCache()
and
Tools :: restoreCacheSettings() , solved this problem.